# computing hash values, integral types versus struct/class

Tags: c++, performance, hash, primitive-types

I would like to know if there is a difference in speed between computing hash value (for example std::map key) of primitive integral type, such as int64_t and pod type, for example `struct { int16_t v[4]; };`.  what about int128_t versus `struct {int32_t v[4];}`?

I know this is going to implementation specific, so my question ultimately pertains to gnu standard library.
Thanks

the link I found very useful
[How can I use a custom type for keys in a boost::unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829639/how-can-i-use-a-custom-type-for-keys-in-a-boostunordered-map)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::map` is not a hash table. It is usually implemented as a balanced binary tree. What you want is `std::unordered_map`* .

And for `std::unordered_map`, C++ only defines the hash value for the internal types and the common ones** such as `std::string`.  You need to implement the hash function for `struct { int16_t v[4]; };` yourself. You can cast this struct into `int64_t` in the computation, then there won't be any difference in hashing speed.

---

<sub>(*: == `std::tr1::unordered_map` == `boost::unordered_map` ≈ `__gnu_cxx::hash_map` == `stdext::hash_map`  etc)</sub>

<sub>(**: 20.8.16 Class template `hash`: ... *integer types (3.9.1), floating-point types (3.9.1), pointer types (8.3.1), and `std::string`, `std::u16string`, `std::u32string`, `std::wstring`, `std::error_code`, `std::thread::id`, `std::bitset`, and `std::vector<bool>`*.)</sub>